Why do delta wells and delta barriers behave equivalently, but normal wells and normal barriers don't?
In Griffith's Intro to QM, it is shown that for $V(x)=-\alpha \delta(x)$ regardless of whether $\alpha$ is positive (a "delta well") or negative (a "delta barrier"), the probability of reflection of a quantum wave packet is the same, namely ${(1 + 2\hbar^2 E/m\alpha^2)}^{-1}$.
However, if we define $V(x)=-\alpha\cdot N(0,\sigma)$, i.e. normally distributed with standard deviation $\sigma$, then this no longer holds. I.e. for sufficiently high $|\alpha|$, the wave packet bounces back for negative $\alpha$ (potential barrier) while it goes through for positive $\alpha$ (potential well).
What explains this difference between delta and normal potentials?

Hint: Consider the case for a square well instead, then you can easily solve the problem analytically and then you can look what happens in the limit for a narrow, deep well and barrier. (Next step: Think about what happens to the wave function qualitatively in the different cases).

@SebastianRiese, by square well do you mean $V(x)=0 \text{ if } x\in[-a,a], \infty \text{ otherwise }$ or do you mean $V(x)=0 \text{ if } x\in[-a,a], \infty \text{ otherwise }$?

I mean a finite square well, otherwise you can't study the scattering (as no wave-packet can reach infinity): $V(x) = -V_0$ for $x \in [-a, a]$ and $V(x) = 0$ otherwise. An infinitely deep square is usually called a box (of course, nomenclature varies – infinite well is also common).
